# Displaying class name in all paragraph or other elements on the page

Tags: javascript

Is there an easy way to select all classes and display it's class name? output and example of what I mean below:

```
<div class="random_div_class">
    <p class="example_lang"></p>
    <p class="example_2_lang"></p>
    <p class="random_lang"></p>
    <a class="random_link_lang"></a>
    <span class="random_span_lang"></span>
</div>
```

to

```
<div class="random_div_class"> // ignore div classes
    <p class="example_lang">example_lang</p>
    <p class="example_2_lang">example_2_lang</p>
    <p class="random_lang">random_lang</p>
    <a class="random_link_lang">random_link_lang</a>
    <span class="random_span_lang">random_span_lang</span>
</div>
```

Unfortunately I have no example code to show because I have to idea where to start. I could also not find a solution online. Any tips are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: There are absolutely examples online of 1. How to select elements, 2. How to get the class(es) on an element, and 3. How to set the text of an element.

Comment: Try: `document.querySelectorAll('p').forEach((p) => { p.innerHTML = p.classList; });`

Comment: Of course I read the question before commenting. There's no reason to be rude.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can first get all the children in the HTML documents
2. Then loop over those children and get the class list to set as a content of that tag

```js
let children = document.getElementsByClassName('random_div_class')[0].children;

for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
  var child = children[i];
  child.innerText = child.classList;
}
```

```html
<div class="random_div_class">
    <p class="example_lang"></p>
    <p class="example_2_lang"></p>
    <p class="random_lang"></p>
    <a class="random_link_lang"></a><br>
    <span class="random_span_lang"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: pretty neat but is there any way to exclude a div element?

Comment: You can exclude a div element by having all those `p` and `a` elements have a secondary class, such as "output" then you can grab the array of elements with said classname and follow that through with what Ankit Agarwal provided

Comment: @Niels you can use `child.tagName !== 'DIV'`. Check the updated answer.

Comment: thanks but all the elements are inside a div and when you use your previous code it only displays the class name of the div. not the `<p>` or `<a>` elements. which is what I want ;)

Comment: Your current code doesn't do anything because it gets rid of all the div elements. I changed my question example.

Comment: I think with this code, to match what Niels is looking for, instead of checking if the tag isn't a div, maybe check if it is and then get the childNodes of that div and have another loop which will set their textContent? Since document.body.children will not include the childNodes of a div

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through all the elements and get the value of class name and put it in the inner text of javascript.

```
var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName("p");

for (var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
    var text = paragraphs[i].getAttribute("class");
  paragraphs[i].innerText = text
}

var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    var text = links[i].getAttribute("class");
  links[i].innerText = text
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ashhaq12345/nj2ht1xu/

Comment: Maybe: `var htmlElements = [...document.getElementsByTagName("a"), ...document.getElementsByTagName("p")];`

Comment: @tcconstantin - `HTMLCollection` isn't officially iterable, even though Chrome makes it iterable. (The `NodeList` returned by `querySelectorAll` is, though.)

Answer (score 0):

Extending on Ankit's answer, this will set the textContent of every element, outside of a div or inside (not including the div) to their className. It will also run correctly if the element does not have a className. If the element has multiple classes, all of those will be shown. e.g. `class="two classes"` will set the text to "two classes".

**Note** The elements affected are only the ones within the body element

```
var elements = document.body.children;

for (el of elements) {
  if (el.tagName == "DIV") {
     for (e of el.children) { // Get children of div element
        e.textContent = e.className;
     }
     continue; // Jump out of the loop so that the div's textContent wont be set by the next line
  }
  el.textContent = el.className;
}
```

Here is the code so you can see if this is the desired output
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G9NXWCHAO6Q3